# Why does virtualbox keep aborting / quitting unexpectedly? MacOS Monterey

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, macos

I am trying to run CSI Linux 2023 on virtualbox, and it has not run a single time. I am a complete beginner, but I have to download 3 virtual machines for my class, but CSI Linux is just 1 and it isn't even working. Here is the error details. Please help.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

The system architecture seems to be ARM-64, which in Mac world means M1/M2.

In these two threads from VirtualBox forums ([Aug 2022](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=107344), [Nov 2022](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=107917); latter showing exact same errors your screenshot shows) the developers clearly state that support for these processors is "nowhere near production-ready", and that to indicate this the GUI is marked "Beta / Developer Preview". Consequently this kind of crashes are to be expected.